# Request [graceful] shutdown of this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

I recently saw the [graceful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graceful) tag on a question that attempted to describe a way to "finalize gracefully".  There are currently 30 questions tagged [graceful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graceful), and the tag wiki is empty.

- 20 of them have to do with gracefully shutting down something
- 4 of them deal with gracefully restarting
- 2 of them mention graceful "solutions"
- 1 of them deals with graceful reload
- 1 of them deals with graceful start/stop
- 1 of them has to do with a Go package called "graceful",
- and the other one is the "finalize gracefully" question I saw recently.

Here are the [burnination criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   It describes the contents, but not by itself, with the exception of the lonely one question about the Go package.  It appears to be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   It may be on topic, but "graceful" by itself doesn't mean anything.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   One would certainly prefer a graceful shutdown to not being able clean up your resources, but it doesn't add any information by itself.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Most questions mean "graceful shutdown"; some of them even have [graceful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graceful) [shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shutdown).  But no, it doesn't mean the same thing in all common contexts.

   A [go-graceful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-graceful) tag may be justifiable, but there is only one question on it.  A [graceful-shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graceful-shutdown) tag may be justifiable.

Should there be a [graceful-shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graceful-shutdown), or should there just be a [graceful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graceful) shutdown?

Comment: Is this tag small enough to use the abbreviated burnination process (i.e. consult w/ another 20k+ user)?

Comment: Either way, I agree with getting rid of this tag. It seems pretty Meta to me.

Comment: 'One would certainly prefer a graceful shutdown to not being able clean up your resources'... fight pending....  :)

Comment: How big can a tagline be?  Can I make one with "Avoiding the usually useless, pointless, time-consuming, occasionally impossible, dangerous, cargo-cult practice of so called 'graceful shutdowns' by user-level code that needs continual testing, updating and fixing with next-to-no gain"?

Comment: Lets gracelessly shut it down.  Terminate it.  Stop its threads and delete its disk space.

Comment: From https://github.com/tylerb/graceful - *Graceful is a Go 1.3+ package enabling graceful shutdown of http.Handler servers.*  So https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072216/how-to-log-messages-for-signaltype-in-tylerb-graceful-in-go is actually about graceful shutdowns also.  Agree with removing the tag despite this.

Comment: @EJoshuaS what's this about an abbreviated process?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I don't remember exactly when it applies, but sometimes for very small tags you're allowed to consult with a 20k+ user and burninate it yourself. (I don't have the exact rules offhand, there's a Meta post about it somewhere).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I got help locating the rule [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination): "If you have authoritative knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have conferred with at least one other trusted community member, and are dealing with a tag that has a small number of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little ad hoc help."

Comment: 1 question should be re-tagged "go-graceful". All tags start with 1 question. That [project has 998 stars on GitHub](//github.com/tylerb/graceful), so may have questions in the future. With a "go-graceful" tag it's less likely someone asking a question about that package will recreate the "graceful" tag. Sounds like the rest of the questions should have the tag removed. You have buy-in from another [trusted user](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), so should be good to go, assuming you judge yourself to "have **authoritative** knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag".

Comment: @Makyen yes, lets keep the  "go-graceful" Q :)

Comment: TBH, the very word 'graceful', when our professional lives are filled with nasty bugs, API's from hell and pages of compiler/linker error dumps, is somewhat offensive.

Comment: If we keep `go-graceful`, should we make `graceful` a synonym? This will make it less likely someone will recreate the `graceful` tag in order to use it as a meta tag on a graceful shutdown question later.

Comment: @Kevin I don't think it should be a synonym.  Users will find a [graceful] tag for their graceful shutdown questions and not even know that it will be changed to [go-graceful].  What is likely is that [go-graceful] will be misused this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have deleted the [graceful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graceful) tag from the 26 remaining questions and edited them to improve many of them.

According to my meta research, the tag script will run at 03:00 UTC and finish the burnination by removing the tag.